# Caspol update previous network share

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, caspol

We have a .Net framework 2 application.

The IIS server points to another server where the code is located (code is network shared).

Already my previous team has used Caspol to FullTrust the network share.

When we moved our code to a new server, and when I run the below command

```
caspol -ag 1 -url file://\\C03SFOECRDSQL51\dnn_main\* FullTrust
```

I still see security exception. System.Security.Policy.PolicyException. and exception mainly from dll `Could not load file or assembly 'effority.MenuNavigationProvider`

I have deleted the previous network share using `caspol -remgroup` from all zones.

Below is the caspol configuration after I used the above command

[image]

Am I doing any wrong ?
Should I re create the strong name, if yes how ?
Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Brr, that server name seems to be designed to mis-type.  My crystal ball says that the web site runs in a 32-bit apppool and thus requires the 32-bit version of Caspol.exe

Comment: The website runs in 64-bit apppool, However after running caspol command  doing an IIS reset did the trick for me. App is loading fine now, but the windows scheduler is throwing an error saying Unable to load DLL webengine.dll. I have created another thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017538/windows-scheduler-service-unable-to-load-dll-webengine-dll